# Excel Unhide Row based on value in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I know there are many questions here about hiding and unhiding rows in excel-vba but I can't seem to get my code to work...

I am working on a spreadsheet that has the month's totals listed on top. I want the sheet to hide the row of any month's total that doesn't appear in the sheet.

For ex. if there is no data in the list for January then the January totals row will be hidden. Once someone puts data for january in the list then the row will unhide.

I know that the script won't be running at all times so I added a "month reset" button that would run the script and hide/unhide all appropriate rows.

For some reason, every time I hit the button, the row just disappears regardless of whether or not the data is in the list below. I only wrote the code for January's row so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("Master Pipeline").Select
For Each cell In Range("B16:B100")
If cell.Value = "January" Then
Range("A3").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
Range("A3").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Cells A3:A14 have the months listed with their totals in the cells next to them.
Rows 16:100 have the list of data, Column B has the month.

Please help...

Thanks in advance,

LT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to hide any months that are missing in the data range. Note that you don't need to (and shouldn't) write code for each month. Also note that **finding** the value in the range is dramatically more efficient than looping through your data range.

Have your button call this sub:

```
Sub HideMissingMonths()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim months As Range
    Dim data As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim found As Range    

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Pipeline")
    Set months = ws.Range("A3:A14")
    Set data = ws.Range("B16:B100")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' unhide all months before we begin
    months.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    For Each cell In months
        Set found = data.Find(what:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If found Is Nothing Then cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```